# jQuery problems in Wordpress Admin panel

Tags: jquery, wordpress, syntax-error, wp-admin

Today I wanted to push my website online since it was all completely done and all running 100% smooth.

I pushed it from my local dev server to a dev branch on my live website (example: dev.domain.com), to see if the transfer would all go OK. It all went well and everything is working on the subdomain.

I did the EXACT same thing but then for my live website (example: domain.com) and everything that the user sees is working but the admin panel is completely broken.

I'm getting 
`"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"` errors in the console (Error is leading to the load-scripts.php file). None of the pictures are loading correctly, the adminbar above is completely broken and I can't fix this problem.

As said everything is completely the same as the dev environment on the same hosting only a different folder and it doesn't work anymore..

**BTW:** Yes I used a seperate database and edited the links correctly in there as well etc. The website itselds functions normally but the admin panel doesn't.

**Images of the errors:**

[admin bar glitching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nf89j.png)

[console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqYiU.png)

Can someone please help me out?

Greets,
Jeroen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772643/uncaught-syntaxerror-invalid-or-unexpected-token-load-scripts-php343-wordpre

Did you clear your cache files or open it in another browser?

Comment: @DaleNguyen Yes I did, unfortunately no results :(